# Files not writing to disk when using formidable/express

Tags: node.js, express, formidable

I have a very simple node script that should just show a static webpage with an upload form and write any uploaded files to disk.

```
const formidable = require('formidable')
const http = require('http')
var fs = require('fs');

const app = express()
const serve = http.Server(app)
const PORT = process.env.PORT || '5000'

// Display upload page at root
app.use(express.static('../client'))

//Start HTTP with express
serve.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on ${PORT}`)
})

app.post('/submit-form', function (req, res){
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

    form.on('fileBegin', function (name, file){
        file.path = __dirname + '/uploads/' + file.name;
    });

    form.parse(req);

    form.on('file', function (name, file){
        console.log('Uploaded ' + file.name);
    });

});

app.listen()
```

The page displays just fine and it send a post request as expected but I get this error after it is uploaded:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open ' the path where the upload should be '
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at lazyFs.open (internal/fs/streams.js:273:12)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:141:20)
```

I can't find anyone with a similar error but I am assuming I am probably doing something stupid.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You must parse the request first before listening to events. Try this:

```
app.post('/submit-form', function (req, res){
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

    form.parse(req)
        .on('fileBegin', function (name, file){
            file.path = __dirname + '/uploads/' + file.name;
        })
        .on('file', function (name, file){
            console.log('Uploaded ' + file.name);
        });
});
```